# Rails error handling/logging: Simplified backtrace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, logging, error-handling

I am working on an **error logging** system for my Rails app, to pick up on any hidden bugs.

So far, I've implemented this with a `rescue_from` on my ApplicationController: (note that I'm in the experimental phase so I'm only outputting the results to the console)

```
   rescue_from Exception, with: :log_exception

   private
    def log_exception exception
      puts("Exception at #{Time.now.strftime('%d %b %Y, %H:%M')}")
      puts exception
      puts exception.backtrace.join "\n"
      raise exception
    end
```

The issue I'm having is with `exception.backtrace`. It outputs a whole bunch of useless deep trace that looks like this

```
/Users/marcoprins/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activemodel-3.2.13/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:407:in `method_missing'
/Users/marcoprins/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:149:in `method_missing'
/Users/marcoprins/Desktop/Project/tillyoudrop/app/models/order.rb:105:in `cancel!'
/Users/marcoprins/Desktop/Project/tillyoudrop/app/controllers/admin/orders_controller.rb:97:in `cancel'
/Users/marcoprins/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
/Users/marcoprins/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
/Users/marcoprins/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
/Users/marcoprins/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
/Users/marcoprins/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:436:in `_run__4209411771832668003__process_action__2626133284113442857__callbacks'
/Users/marcoprins/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
/Users/marcoprins/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
/Users/marcoprins/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
```

and it goes on for miles and miles.

I want my error log file to look clean and readable, so all I want is essentialy the 3rd and 4th line of this example, or rather, the exact lines that Rails outputs in the error page, (see picture) the part that tells me exactly **where in my code** the error has originated from.

[image: Rails error page]

How do I access these lines? Is there an attribute on the `exception` object that contains it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reject or select certain lines by pattern match with the files/directories you want to extract or ignore. For example, if you want to ignore the steps in `/gems/`, then:

```
exception.backtrace.reject{|l| l =~ %r|\A[^:]*/gems/|}
```

If you want only the steps from `/app/` directory, then:

```
exception.backtrace.select{|l| l =~ %r|\A[^:]*/app/|}
```

Actually, you should be using `backtrace_locations` instead of `backtrace`, which gives direct access to paths without using regexes, but for the time being, `backtrace_locations` is full of bugs, and it is not practical to use it.

Comment: I also thought of filtering the lines via regex. But does it not have a high performance cost?

Comment: Errors are not supposed to happen under regular use. Ideally, and usually, they only occur during development, or just a once in a while during production use. Therefore, performance of error manipulation is usually not a problem. Furthermore, a backtrace usually does not exceed a few hundred lines. Regex matching with such lines will not be a major performance loss.